# jquery timepicker addon to mysql lookup range

Tags: jquery, mysql, datepicker, datetimepicker

i have to inputs that i want to format in an easy to read format, however when the user selects the date, i need the output to be in a format that mysql can handle. i dont think i can change the view format independantly from the output format. so im trying to achieve what i want by using hidden input elements and alt field in timepicker but i seem to be missing something. is there a better way of doing this or am i on the right track, i can't seem to get it to work.

```
$('.startDate').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat  : "hh:mm tt",
    separator: ' ',
    showTimezone: false,
    altField: ".startDateHidden",
    altFieldTimeOnly: false,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    altTimeFormat: "h:m t",
    altSeparator: " "
});

$('.endDate').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat  : "hh:mm tt",
    separator: ' ',
    showTimezone: false,
    altField: ".endDateHidden",
    altFieldTimeOnly: false,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    altTimeFormat: "h:m t",
    altSeparator: " "
});

$('.startDate, .endDate, .startDateHidden, .endDateHidden').datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()) );
```

EDIT:
well later in my code i make a call to the hidden fields to use the dates in an ajax call, but the getDate is returning empty for the hidden elements, being var date3 and date4

```
var date1 = $('.startDate').datetimepicker('getDate');
var date2 = $('.startDate').datetimepicker('getDate');
var date3 = $('.startDateHidden').datetimepicker('getDate');
var date4 = $('.endDateHidden').datetimepicker('getDate');
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
console.log(date3);
console.log(date4);
```

Comment: The general idea of how you're doing it sounds perfectly reasonable. Try describing the exact problems you're having with it and show the code that seems not to be working properly.

Comment: well later in my code i make a call to the hidden fields to use the dates in an ajax call, but the getDate is returning empty for the hidden elements, being var date3 and date4

Comment: And when you unhide .startDateHidden and .endDateHidden they work just fine? And you're sure that the only difference between the working ones and the failing ones is that they failing ones are hidden? Is your code too cumbersome for a fiddle to demonstrate the problem? In fact, breaking it down small enough for a fiddle might shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i did overlook something.

i completely forgot that the hidden inputs aren't initiated by the datetimepickerso i have to get there value manually with jquery with val()

```
var date3 = $('.startDateHidden').val();
var date4 = $('.endDateHidden').val();
```